# If the differentiation of a formula is larger than 0,the formula must be convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

[image]

Now i know all parameters are positive,i mean, $g_{AB},g_{A},g_{AC},P_{B2AC},P_{C2AB},P_{A2BC},\mu$ and $N_0$ are all > $0$,and the only variable $\rho^{st}_A  \in [0,1].$

I think the formula i mention above is convex,because its differentiation is larger than $0$,is my thinking right? or should i consider about other condition?

Comment: Depending on which variables in which you'd like to check if this function is convex, it might be easier to simply check the [definition of convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition)

Comment: When you say "It's differentiation" do you mean the first derivative? Second derivative? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function

Comment: @Scott For the variable : $\rho_A ^{st}$

Comment: @KitterCatter yes , It's differentiation" means the first derivative,so the  Second derivative has to larger than $0$ too?

Comment: In order to be convex the second derivative would need to be larger than 0.

Comment: for $x>0$ the first derivative of each $g(x)=x^2$ and $h(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is positive, but only one of these two functions is convex. So it is not that 2nd derivative has to be larger than $0$ "too", it is only about 2nd derivative, and not at all about 1st derivative.